# Writing own scaffold generator, exporting as a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have created my own scaffold generator, now it's sitting in my ~/.rails/generator/scaffold directory. How can I make a gem in order to use my generator along other machines I'm using, without the need of copying the ~/.rails folder on every box ? I will push later the gem on Github

Comment: I've looked into this before, but I never came to a conclusion either way. I was hoping to do something similar. I am very interested to see if anyone has a good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generator.html):

> For a RubyGem, put your generator
>   class and templates in the lib
>   directory. For a Rails plugin, make a
>   generators directory at the root of
>   your plugin.

However that's a little vague.

From the Rails::Generator::Lookup source:

1. Rails application.  If RAILS_ROOT is defined we know we're
   generating in the context of a Rails application, so search
   RAILS_ROOT/generators.
2. Look in plugins, either for generators/ or rails_generators/ 
   directories within each plugin
3. User home directory.  Search ~/.rails/generators.
4. RubyGems.  Search for gems named *_generator, and look for 
   generators within any RubyGem's 
   /rails_generators/_generator.rb file.
5. Builtins.  Model, controller, mailer, scaffold, and so on.

A single generator gem should be structured like this:

- my_scaffold_generator/

  - lib/
  - my_scaffold_generator.rb
  - required_file.rb
  - templates/
  - ...

Gems that contains multiple generators should be structured like this:

- my_cool_generators/

  - rails_generators/
  - cool_scaffold/
  - cool_scaffold_generator.rb
  - lib/

    - required_file.rb
    - ...
  - templates/

    - ...
  - cool_controller/
  - cool_controller_generator.rb
  - lib/

    - required_files.rb
    - ...
  - templates/

    - ...